# Passing a location to web api using json

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, geolocation, json.net

```
[DataContract]
public partial class Event
{
    [DataMember]
    public int EventId { get; set; }        
    [DataMember]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    [Required]
    public string EventDescription { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    [Column(TypeName = "smalldatetime")]
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int ActivityId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DbGeography Location { get; set; }
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public virtual Activity Activity { get; set; }
}
```

I have the above class in web api and my get all and get by id functions work. Here is an example of the json they return:

```
{
"EventId": 6,
"UserId": "1",
"EventDescription": "Auckland city test",
"Timestamp": "2015-02-11T00:00:00",
"ActivityId": 1,
"Location": {
"Geography": {
"CoordinateSystemId": 4326,
"WellKnownText": "POINT (180.756117 -30.85824)"
}
}
}
```

However if i pass the same json back to the post method it is not able to convert the location to a dbgeography type. I have tried formatting the location in different ways but always get a nullReferenceException in location.

Is there a particular way I should format the location in json? I would have thought that if it serializes to that format it would be able to de-serialize that format.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sending the ``Content-Type: application/json`` header when you do your ``POST``?